# Отступ от соседнего элемента

Tags: css

```css
#content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#account {
  height: 450px;
  width: 390px;
  background: #4b4b4b;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  float: right;
}
#account_header,
#vote_header {
  text-align: center;
  width: 390px;
  height: 70px;
  background: #626262;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #FFF;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
#test {
  margin-right: 15px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 390px;
  background: #4b4b4b;
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
#t1,
#all {
  height: 100px;
  width: 187.5px;
  background: #4b4b4b;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#t1 {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
#vote {
  height: 500px;
  width: 390px;
  background: #4b4b4b;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  float: right;
}
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Preview</title>
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="content" class="clearfix">
      <div id="account" class="center-block">
        <div id="account_header">Аккаунт</div>
      </div>
      <div id="test">
        <div id="t1">
        </div>
        <div id="all">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="vote">
        <div id="vote_header">
          Голосование
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Имеется несколько блоков, все они позиционируются относительно верхней границы блока content. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы они "отступали" друг от друга, а именно: test от account, vote от test и т.д.

Comment: А где блок online?

Comment: Извиняюсь, очепяточка. 
Блок test

Comment: Я открыл выполнение вашего кода и у вас отступы между этими блоками. Вообще такое делается свойством margin-right, оно у вас есть в свойствах указанных элементов.

Comment: Вы открывали страницу в полном размере?

Comment: Да, я так вижу `http://s31.postimg.org/6k0r99ni3/2016_04_24_21_22_06.png`. Тут отступы есть.

Comment: Мне необходимо, чтобы блоки были друг под другом, и отступы для каждого элемента отсчитывались от границ верхнего блока. Такое вообще возможно?

Comment: Уберите у них свойство `float: right `и они будут друг под другом. Для отступов сверху соответственно использовать `margin-top`

Comment: Благодарю за помощь. А можно сделать так, чтобы каждый блок позиционировался относительно предыдущего?

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю что вы имеете в виду. Напишите подробнее или на примере.

Comment: Имеются блоки t1, t2, t3 и t4. Блоки t2, t3 и t4 расположены в t1. margin-top в свойствах t2 задает отступ от границ t1, margin-top в свойствах t3 задает отступ от границ t2, margin-top в свойствах t4 задает отступ от границ t3. При этом все блоки располагаются последовательно друг под другом.

Comment: Так должно быть или так сейчас?

Comment: Должно быть. В идеале.

Comment: Попробуйте свойство `position: relative`

Comment: Не помогло, к сожалению.